# android application crash after launch

Tags: java, android

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {
static int i = 0;
static  int p = 0;

String porc0;
TextView tvporc;
Button btn;
TextView tvresult;
String mutqbar;
char generacvac;
char mutq;
int mutqitiv;
int generacvacitiv;
EditText et;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    Random random = new Random();
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    tvporc=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPorc);
    tvresult=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    generacvac=(char)(random.nextInt(26)+'a');
    tvresult.setText(generacvac);
    generacvacitiv = (int) generacvac;
    et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tvresult.setText(generacvac);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mutqbar = et.getText().toString();
            try {
                mutq = mutqbar.charAt(0);
                mutqitiv = (int) mutq;
                if (mutqitiv<97 || mutqitiv>122){
                    tvporc.setText("Մուտքագրեք տառ");
                }
                int abs = Math.abs(mutqitiv-generacvacitiv);
                if (abs>0 && abs<5) tvresult.setText("Դու շատ մոտ ես!");
                else if (abs>=5 && abs<10) tvresult.setText("Դու մոտ ես~");
                else if(abs>=10) tvresult.setText("Դու հեռու ես~");

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                tvresult.setText("Դաշտը դատարկ է");
            }


        }

    });



}}
```

I have this code, but when I run it, it returns error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.guessit.guessit/com.guessit.guessit.Game}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x66. and crush on device.Already 1 hour I'm trying to find the problem. please help me

Comment: Give the complete log trace

Comment: show your activity_game

Comment: It's the game activity

Comment: @KDeogharkar is asking to show XML file

Comment: sorry if I am not specific . activity_game.xml

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I already find the solution. I writed tvresult.setText(generacvac); but it cast to int, and I need to write tvresult.setText(generacvac+"")